# How to count the call trace of a function in kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there a light-weight method to count the call trace of a function(eg. __schedule) in kernel?
I want to know the major entries of a key function.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question right, but I will give it a shot. 
If you want to get some informations about a function/define/... from the linux kernel, I can recommend you the site: [Bootlin](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source) 
Simply search for your function and you will get every occurance of this function in the selected kernel version.

You also could import the complete kernel into your workspace and use your ide of choice to determine the call trace but this solution is not light weight.